# PIC programming in C: if any in list is true then

Tags: c, pic, mplab

Newbie to C programming.  I'm programming a PIC in MPLAB X IDE. How can create an if statement whereby if any items in a list are true then... else...?

If [either a>10, b>10, or c>10] 
Then panic
Else carry on

Do I really have to right the block of code three times (or in my case 10)?

Comment: You need the logical OR operator - `||`.

Comment: `if ( a>10 ||  b>10)` is a good start.  Other simplifications possible for 10 items, yet need to see more of your code first.

Comment: This is what, the 2nd half of the first hour in any C tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You need the logical OR opertator(`||`):

```
if (a > 10 || b > 10 || c > 10)
{
    panic();
}
else
{
    carry_on();
)
```